# AWS - S3 to RDS(postgres) import using aws_s3 extension (provided by RDS) is failing

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have successfully created a role with policy attached to that role which allows required actions on the bucket. Policy document is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "s3import",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And then i attached this role to my RDS instance with feature s3Import.

This is the command i ran.

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'table name',
   '', 
   'DELIMITER ''|''',
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
       'bucket-name',
       'file.csv',
       'region')
);
```

I am getting this error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: HTTP 404. Requested file does not exist.
```

Is anything missing here ?

Comment: The error msg is about file which does not exist, not about access deny to S3. Are you certain that the `file.csv` exists where you expect it to be?

Comment: you are correct, file name was incorrect, please post your comment and i will mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Based on the error message provided, the issue was not due to access deny to S3, but rather due to **wrong file name** used in `create_s3_uri`.

The **solution** was to use the correct file name.